# Custom Exception Handler C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have Made custom Exception Handler in C# I want to show a readable message for the user if any Exception occurred.

I have tried to specify the Exception pending on it's Hresult Value but I have a problem that I haven't seen, which is showing Hresult value and the specified exception

```
 class UiException : Exception
{
    public string Errormessage { get; set; }
    public UiException(Exception e)
  : base()
    {
        string exName = e.Source;
        int errorNumber =  e.HResult;
        if (e.HResult == -2146233080)
            Errormessage = "Index was outside the bounds of the array.";

 }     
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I've misinterpreted this, but are you asking how you would present this to the operator?  If so, take a look at MessageBox.Show().

Comment: I want to handle every exception may occur pending HResult value

Comment: @AhmedElBatrawy - This is a definition of an exception. It's not an exception handler. That would be part of a `try`/`catch`.

Comment: @Enigmativity thans for replay I had found  A full list of HRESULTs and I have convert it to HEX then I have doing my task :D [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/yizhang/2010/12/17/interpreting-hresults-returned-from-netclr-0x8013xxxx/)

Comment: What do you mean by "I have try to specify the Exception pending on It's Hresult Value but I have a problem that I haven't **sheet** which showing Hresult value and the specified exception "?

Comment: First of all you shouldn't be exposing exceptions to end user. Imagine you run Skype or Chrome and you see `Index was outside the bounds of the array.`. This is useless to the end user.This is only for debugging purposes. If you really want to do this (which I don't recommend), just use dictionary with each `HResult` and retrieve it this way. It's much cleaner and faster.

Comment: I think you're mixing up what `Exceptions` are. They basically contain the information necessary to track down unexpected or unintended behaviour in the program and are meant to be used with the `throw` and `try`/`catch`/`finally` behaviour. Usually you would create the message to display to the user within the `catch` block according to what you tried to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not want to use HRESULT for exception identification. HRESULT is mainly there for COM interop and is of little use in .NET. I would recommend the following:

1. Use the type of the base exception to figure out your custom error message. You stay in .NET and it is more flexible. The main advantage in terms of flexibility is that you can easily cover exceptions derived from other exceptions without having to define a fallback. Also, with an `as`cast you can easily extract further information from the exception (such as the `ParameterName` of an `ArgumentException`).
2. Make your base exception an inner exception. Inner exceptions are there since the dawn of <strike>time</strike> .NET and therefore are widely supported, e.g. for logging or debugging. Keeping the source of the error is also good for error analysis and general best practice.
3. There is absolutely no need for your `Errormessage` property. There is a `Message` property, which suits your purpose and (like the inner exception) is widely supported.

So your custom exception should look more like this:

```
class UIException : Exception
{
    public UIException(Exception baseException) :
        base(GetErrorMessage(baseException), baseException)
    {
    }

    private static GetErrorMessage(Exception baseException)
    {
        if (baseException is IndexOutOfRangeException)
        {
            return "Index was outside the bounds of the array.";
        }
        else if (exception is InvalidOperationException)
        {
            //Return exception message
        }
        //... more else if in the chain
        else
        {
            return baseException.Message;
        }
    }
}
```